# WHM/Cpanel wrong mail host after using transfer tool

Tags: email, cpanel, exim

I'm out of options. After using the WHM transfer tool to copy my entire cpanel account to my other server for testing (did that several times without problems) there were a lot of problems, als see

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/transfer-tool-issues.678209/

After changing back the .htaccess the site was up-and-running again. Also i did the dovecot and exim reset. Mail is sending, but incoming mail is a problem. It seems that there is a redirect or something only for incomming mail. I get this faults:

Cpanel mail

SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:jilco@tricotstoffen.nl: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.\n550-cloud.tricotstoffen.nl [31.186.173.214]:50078 is not permitted to relay\n550 through this server without authentication.

Bounced mail (hotmail)

host cloud.meisjemeis.nl [31.186.173.208]
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:jilco@tricotstoffen.nl:
550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.
550-cloud.tricotstoffen.nl [31.186.173.214]:48250 is not permitted to relay
550 through this server without authentication.

The last one contains the wrong host (cloud.meisjemeis.nl is not the correct one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason the /etc/manualmx was changed. Setting the correct value did the job

Comment: Thank you for this post. I would have never guessed this. I just removed the entry for the domain and it resolved the problem since I was referencing a remote MX record.

Comment: thats right, manualmx cause this issue

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step to solve this issue.

->login in Cpanel account.

->Type "Email Routing" in the search bar or find it in the "Email" section.

->On the next page, choose your domain from the drop-down list.

->Once you've selected the domain, you will want to make sure it's set to "local mail exchanger", then click change.

Obviously, if the domain is already using the "local" option, you don't need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

we created new dev server, but mail troubleshooter in whm was pointing to new server, this answer helped me to fix the issue